# Chrome Extension: Capture entire page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome plugin. I want to Capture the entire page rather than just the visible area. I found that Chrome provides API calls where we can capture only the visible part of the screen using

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab
```

How can I capture the entire page? Is there any native solution or do we need to go for other plugins for extensions? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at the (still experimental) [savePage API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.savePage.html):